# typeof equivalent of .NET for ABL Progress Openedge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have added System.Messaging to my assemblies.xml cause I need to use this in my Progress OpenEdge application. However I ran into a problem.

In C# when assigning:

```
m.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(TrowConfiguration) });
TrowConfiguration myConfiguration = m.Body as TrowConfiguration;
```

However I now want to do this in ABL. I first used a method to read a string and just passed a `CHARACTER EXTENT 1 INITIAL "System.String"` to the XmlMessageFormatter object. However I tried changing this to the path of my object, TrowConfiguration, but this doesn't work and gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the System.Type reference, use

`Progress.Util.TypeHelper:GetType ("<your fully qualified type name>").`

Comment: Hello, I'm using your framework to deserialize the object, typeof is now working however when I'm doing this I get this error: Could not dynamically find class 'List'.

Comment: Where is List referenced? In the XML string? Sounds like that should be referenced as a full type name. Not an abbreviated one.

Comment: You will have to stick completely to .NET types. The .NET XmlMessageFormatter has no knowledge of ABL Types/classes at all. So use a System.Collections.List instead.

Comment: I don't really get it sorry... Quite new to abl and your framework. But when I use "System.String" in the XMLMessageFormatter I can acces the Body of this message and put it in a longchar (image in OP), how come I can't deserialize then?